# Classic ASP Response.redirect encoding issue

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have some legacy classic ASP code in vbscript I'm supporting which redirects through to different URLs.

I have one problem with response.redirect on the following URL:

http://www.michelson.pl/kolczyki-z-bialego-zlota-z-2-diamentami-o-szlifie-princess-masy-0-40ct;1363853/

The response.redirect seems to encode the `;` to `%3B` generating the below which is an invalid URL:

http://www.michelson.pl/kolczyki-z-bialego-zlota-z-2-diamentami-o-szlifie-princess-masy-0-40ct%3B1363853/

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Comment: The URL is not invalid it's just encoded `%3B` is the URL encoded form of `;`. If you want to get back to the decoded form you need a `UrlDecode()` function which I'm sure there are samples of on the internet. Used [URLDecode function](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_URLDecode/) from [Motobit Software](http://www.motobit.com/) in the past which works well. Useful article on [Using Server.URLEncode](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042601-1.shtml) on [4Guys From Rolla](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem seems to be that Response.redirect is adding the %3B encoding - the string we are passing in is unencoded. I don't know of a way to unencode the value once its already been passed to Response.Redirect unencoded.

Comment: Yes, that's because it's designed to do that - [URL Encoding
(or: 'What are those "%20" codes in URLs?')](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) *(`;` is  a reserved character in the RFC 1738 spec)*

Comment: Quote from [RFC 1738 - 2.2. URL Character Encoding Issues](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) - *"If the character corresponding to an octet is reserved in a scheme, the octet must be encoded."*

Comment: I know its a reserved character - that is the problem. I don't have any control over the destination URL. Encoding the URL or replacing that character with an encoded value doesn't solve the issue either.

Comment: Hey a simple thanks would suffice. You know it's a reserved character but you don't seem to understand why it's being encoded?? I think I'll take my leave.

Comment: @Lankymart I completely understand that its an issue with reserved characters but that wasn't what I was asking. I'm looking for a way around it - like the answer I've posted below - which seems to act as a workaround to the issue with Response.Redirect.

Comment: If the target server is non-conforming, this workaround can be necessary. ad.doubleclick.net seems to be one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit more googling it seems there is a possible way around this using the following to create a redirect via headers:

```
Response.Status = "302 Object Moved"
Response.AddHeader "Location", url
Response.Write "<HTML>"
Response.Write "<BODY>"
Response.Write "This file was moved to "
Response.Write "<A HREF=""" & url & """>here.<A>"
Response.Write "</BODY>"
Response.Write "</HTML>"
Response.End
```

This creates a successful redirect to http://www.michelson.pl/kolczyki-z-bialego-zlota-z-2-diamentami-o-szlifie-princess-masy-0-40ct;1363853/ with no encoding of the ; to %3B

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the ";". You could split the string of url by ";" and then you can delete the part after ";". I have viewed that the link run too.

Comment: The whole URL needs to be present. We can't remove any portion of it. The ; has to stay in some form.